# How to dynamically bind service bus BrokeredMessage in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using the service bus with an azure function. The function is triggered by a queue, then the ReplyTo property on the input BrokeredMessage is to be used as the queue to respond on. How can I dynamically bind to the output queue? I've tried the code below, but get:

> Can't bind ServiceBus to type
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage'.

```
public static async Task Run(BrokeredMessage msg, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message");
    var msgout = await binder.BindAsync<BrokeredMessage>(new ServiceBusAttribute(msg.ReplyTo));
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "myInputQueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsServiceBus",
      "accessRights": "Manage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For output scenarios, you need to bind to type **IAsyncCollector**:

```
public static async Task Run(
    BrokeredMessage msg, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message");
    var collector = await binder.BindAsync<IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage>>(
                        new ServiceBusAttribute(msg.ReplyTo));

    var message = ...
    await collector.AddAsync(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Would be nice if this could be done declaratively as it seems like a typical scenario to reply to the queue specified on the ReplyTo Property.

Comment: Agreed. We had a related issue in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1004) for expanding the set of built in binding data properties for EventHub trigger. We'll do the same for ServiceBus.